# How to store the submitted form information in MySQL?

Tags: orbeon

I have configured Orbeon to use MySQL as explained in the general documentation. It works with some [limitations](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Column-username-not-found-error-when-searching-or-showing-form-summary-td4657308.html). Now I have published a form and I can fill it up.

When submitted the information is stored somewhere, but I don't know where (probably in eXistdb). How can also configure Orbeon to also store submissions in MySQL? I want to access to this information from external applications.

Comment: I hope that my answer below will help, but in case it doesn't, and you have more information on the issue, feel free to add a comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` process [as of 4.2](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-4.2-ce/src/resources-packaged/config/properties-form-runner.xml#L202) runs the following [actions](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Buttons-and-Processes#core-actions):

```
require-uploads then require-valid then save 
then success-message("save-success") then result-dialog 
recover error-message("database-error")
```

So it does save the data. However, you're saying that you don't see the data saved in MySQL. To simplify things, you can start by trying to check of the data gets saved when you hit just the *Save* button on the same form. And if it doesn't get saved, see if there are any errors in the `orbeon.log`. If you see an error, but not enough information about it, you can increase the log level by using the [development configuration](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration).

Comment: You are right, data are in MySQL database (in `orbeon_form_data` table). Probably I am confused with this table because previously I cannot recognize the submitted information there. But I have checked it again and there are all the XML structure. No errors in `orbeon.log` and everything is working fine. Thanks for your comments, you have pointed me to the right path.